# Lemmatizing using Spacy

Tags: lemmatization

I have a list which contains sentences.

`list = ["I'm hoping to go jogging", "I haven't eaten in a while","where is everybody going"]`

I want to lemmatize the above list and replace the original words with the lemma's.

how do I do it using spacy?

I know I could print the lemma's in a loop but what I want is to replace the original word with the lemmatized.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like what you're looking for:

```
import spacy
from spacy.en import English
parser = English()

list = ["I'm hoping to go jogging", "I haven't eaten in a while","where is everybody going", 
    "Hello, how are you? I'm doing good."]
lemmatized_list = []

for sentence in list:
    tokens = parser(sentence)
    lemmas = []
    for tok in tokens:
        if not tok.is_punct:
            lemmas.append(tok.lemma_.lower().strip() if tok.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else tok.lower_)
    lemmatized_phrase = ""
    for l in lemmas:
        lemmatized_phrase += l + " "
    lemmatized_phrase = lemmatized_phrase[:-1]
    lemmatized_list.append(lemmatized_phrase)
print (lemmatized_list)

>>> ['i be hop to go jogging', "i haven't eat in a while", 'where be everybody go', 'hello how be you i be do good']
```

Comment: this looks alright except, if there are sentences like "Hello, how are you? I'm doing good.". The comma and fullstop will be taken as another word. How do i get them as it is. I want to make it look like -  "hello, how be you? i be do good."

Comment: @AshanWijenayake Tokenize first, then lemmatize, then join lemmatized tokens? Nasically remove the `tok.is_punct` from the above code.

Comment: I put the `tok.is_punct` in there cause he didn't want the question marks and other punctuation in the result